# Wordpress/PHP: how to place meta tag at top of head

Tags: php, html, wordpress, meta

So, I have this PHP function that adds the X-UA-Compatible meta tag to the head of every page of my Wordpress site. (I'm new to Wordpress and PHP so forgive me about terminology). It's in the functions.php file of my StudioPress child theme.

The problem is the tag only works if it's placed very near the top, and the way I have it set up now causes the tag to appear halfway down, so it doesn't work. How can I force this tag to appear at the top of the head of each page?

Comment: Why would the order of the elements in the `<head>` tag even matter?

Comment: You should always provide an example of the code you are trying to fix. You mention a php function but we can't see it. The answer provided by Damith should work.

Answer (score 6):

Ex : You can use `wp_head` action. The wp_head action hook is triggered within the `<head></head>` section of the user's template by the `wp_head()` function. Although this is theme-dependent, it is one of the most essential theme hooks, so it is widely supported.

```
function aaa_custom_function() {
    ?>
       Your Tag
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'aaa_custom_function', 1000);
```

Use the third parameter to control the position. Change 1000 to another values to find the perfect position.

Comment: Stop playing the rollback game on this answer. This is abusive behavior and will not be tolerated. For your information, no, you are not automatically blocked from doing this, but it will alert moderators so we can check to see if what you are doing is actually legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom hook like this way.

open **header.php** then write this below line where you want to show meta tag

```
<?php do_action("my_custom_metatags");?>
```

Now open your **functions.php** and write down this below code

```
function my_custom_metatags_fn()
{
//your tag goes here.
}
add_action("my_custom_metatags","my_custom_metatags_fn");

//Test this code it will work like a charm for you.
```

Answer (score 1):

adding to @Damith answer `wp_head` action will work.

[Refrence](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head)

also you can override `header.php` file into your child theme.

add this code in `function.php`

```
<?php function your_custom_function() {
       // your custom code which you want to add in header file
}
add_action('wp_head', 'your_custom_function', 1);
```